# Solving the false "theorem" $\int\frac1{f(x)}dx=\frac1{\int f(x)dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, complex-numbers

For fun, I am trying to solve the false "theorem"
$$\int\frac1{f(x)}dx=\frac1{\int f(x)dx}$$
for all functions $f$ that satisfy the above equation. I got a solution but it seems to be wrong, and I was wondering where it went wrong. Here's how I did it:

I first started by differentiating both sides, using Chain Rule on the RHS:
$$\frac1{f(x)}=-\frac{f(x)}{(\int f(x)dx)^2}$$
Cross multiplying, I get:
$$-(f(x))^2=\left(\int f(x)dx\right)^2$$
So:
$$\int f(x)dx=\sqrt{-(f(x))^2}$$
Then, differentiating both sides again:
$$f(x)=\frac12(-(f(x))^2)^{-1/2}\cdot(-2f(x))\cdot f'(x)$$
Which simplifies to (I switch from $f(x)$ to $y$ from here to make it easier to keep track of the variables):
$$y=-(-y^2)^{-1/2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Separating the variables:
$$dx=\frac{-(-y^2)^{-1/2}}ydy$$
At this point I'm not sure what else to do so I introduce the imaginary numbers into the equation (this is where it starts getting iffy for me, because I never mixed imaginary numbers with integration before):
$$dx=\frac{-(-1)^{-1/2}\cdot(y^2)^{-1/2}}ydy$$
$$dx=\frac{-1/i}{y^2}dy$$
$$\int dx=-\frac1i\int\frac1{y^2}dy$$
$$x+C_1=-\frac1i\cdot\left(-\frac1y+C_2\right)$$
$$x+C_1=\frac1{yi}+C_2$$
$$x+C_3=\frac1{yi}$$
$$yi=\frac1{x+C_3}$$
$$\boxed{f(x)=\frac1{ix+C}}$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary complex number.

But the problem with this solution is when I try to plug this back into the original equation, it doesn't seem to make the equation true. For example, let's say I choose $C=0$, so that $f(x)=\frac1{ix}$. Then the LHS becomes:
$$\int\frac1{f(x)}dx=\int ixdx=i\frac{x^2}2+C_4$$
But the RHS becomes:
$$\frac1{\int f(x)dx}=\frac1{\int\frac1{ix}dx}=\frac1{\frac1i\ln|x|+C_5}$$
which obviously don't match each other at all.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2058212/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $y=-(-y^2)^{-1/2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$

Here you forgot the term $-2f(x)$ from the previous equation.

In general if you write $\int f(x)dx=\sqrt{-(f(x))^2}$ then you are already working with complex numbers because of $(f(x))^2>0$. It would be easier to define $g:=\int f$. The you get the equations
$-(g')^2 = g^2$ or by taking roots $g' = \pm i\cdot g$.

Comment: Ah shoot I simplified a little and canceled the $\frac12$ and $-2$, but I guess I canceled the $f(x)$ too on accident... I will see what answer I come up with after I fix this error!

Comment: I was also wondering if I was handling the complex numbers correctly? This is my first time using complex numbers with integration and differentiation so I was wondering if treating them as constants is ok.

Comment: Yes, you can treat complex numbers as constants.

Comment: roots of complex numbers is a bigger topic. There are basically two issues to deal with. First you have always two solutions for a square root. Second if a function is zero a a point you get a branching point so the root is not always defined nearby.